# transitionCoordinator return nil for custom container view controller in iOS8

Tags: ios, uicontainerview, uipresentationcontroller, transition-coordinator

when reference `transitionCoordinator` on child vc, it used to called `transitionCoordinator` on custom container class in iOS7, but in iOS8 this wasn't the case. Now it return nil and I have no clue what should I change to make this work.

I guess its about UIPresentationController introduced in iOS8, but can't find proper implementation for custom container view controller.

Comment: Did you ever find what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

As Matt said in this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964570/3857555):

> So, since you can't even get a transition coordinator in a situation
>   where you are allowed to write a custom transition animation for a
>   built-in parent view controller, obviously the chances of your getting
>   one in a situation where you're trying to do your own parent view
>   controller are zero

But, according to [transitionCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619294-transitioncoordinator), overriding it is allowed:

> Container view controllers can override this method but in most cases
>   should not need to. If you do override this method, first call super
>   to see if there is an appropriate transition coordinator to return,
>   and, if there is, return it.

So, I would try to create my own coordinator for my own VC container. If you use a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to manipulate the VC container's children, it's almost straightforward.

Here is an example:

```
class PropertyAnimatorTransitionCoordinator: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext {

    private let parentView: UIView
    private let fromViewController: UIViewController?
    private let toViewController: UIViewController
    private let animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator

    // MARK: - Life Cycle

    init(parentView: UIView,
         fromViewController: UIViewController?,
         toViewController: UIViewController,
         animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator) {
        self.parentView = parentView
        self.fromViewController = fromViewController
        self.toViewController = toViewController
        self.animator = animator
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator

    func animate(alongsideTransition animation: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)?,
                 completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)? = nil) -> Bool {
        var isSuccessful = false
        if let animation = animation {
            animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
                guard let context = self else { return }
                animation(context)
            }
            isSuccessful = true
        }
        if let completion = completion {
            animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
                guard let context = self else { return }
                completion(context)
            }
            isSuccessful = true
        }
        return isSuccessful
    }

    func animateAlongsideTransition(in view: UIView?, animation: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)?, completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)? = nil) -> Bool {
        return animate(alongsideTransition: animation, completion: completion)
    }

    func notifyWhenInteractionEnds(_ handler: @escaping (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) {
        animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            guard let context = self else { return }
            handler(context)
        }
    }

    func notifyWhenInteractionChanges(_ handler: @escaping (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) {
        animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            guard let context = self else { return }
            handler(context)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext

    var isAnimated: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var presentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }

    var initiallyInteractive: Bool {
        return false
    }

    var isInterruptible: Bool {
        return animator.isInterruptible
    }

    var isInteractive: Bool {
        return animator.isUserInteractionEnabled
    }

    var isCancelled: Bool {
        return !animator.isRunning
    }

    var transitionDuration: TimeInterval {
        return animator.duration
    }

    var percentComplete: CGFloat {
        return animator.fractionComplete
    }

    var completionVelocity: CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    var completionCurve: UIView.AnimationCurve {
        return animator.timingParameters?.cubicTimingParameters?.animationCurve ?? .linear
    }

    var targetTransform: CGAffineTransform {
        return .identity
    }

    var containerView: UIView {
        return parentView
    }

    func viewController(forKey key: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey) -> UIViewController? {
        switch key {
        case .from:
            return fromViewController
        case .to:
            return toViewController
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func view(forKey key: UITransitionContextViewKey) -> UIView? {
        switch key {
        case .from:
            return fromViewController?.view
        case .to:
            return toViewController.view
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

In my custom container, I would use it like this:

```
class CustomContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    private var customTransitionCoordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?

    override var transitionCoordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator? {
        if let coordinator = super.transitionCoordinator {
            return coordinator
        }
        return customTransitionCoordinator
    }

    override var shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods: Bool {
        return false
    }

    func insertNewChild(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .easeInOut)
        customTransitionCoordinator = PropertyAnimatorTransitionCoordinator(
            parentView: view,
            fromViewController: nil,
            toViewController: viewController,
            animator: animator
        )
        animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            guard let parent = self else { return }
            viewController.didMove(toParent: parent)
            self?.customTransitionCoordinator = nil
        }
        addChild(viewController)
        viewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        let target = view.bounds
        viewController.view.frame = target
        viewController.view.frame.origin.x = -target.width
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        animator.addAnimations {
            viewController.view.frame = target
        }
        animator.addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            guard let parent = self else { return }
            viewController.endAppearanceTransition()
            viewController.didMove(toParent: parent)
            self?.customTransitionCoordinator = nil
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

Of course, some edge cases are not handled. It's a really basic example.