# How can I get UIKit to provide me with a transition coordinator for a custom transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm writing a custom container view controller that manages multiple child view controllers, kind of like `UIPageViewController` does.

I would like clients to be able to animate stuff outside its area of responsibility alongside an interactive transition between its child view controllers, but I can't seem to find a way to get UIKit to give me a transition coordinator.

Do I really have to make a custom class implementing this protocol for such a simple task? If so, how would I go about implementing `-animateAlongsideTransition:completion:`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the kind of transition coordinator you get from a child view controller (i.e. the `transitionCoordinator` property of a UIViewController), you're not going to be able to get one from the system. Such transition coordinators are supplied only under a very limited set of circumstances.

For example, you are allowed to write a custom transition animation, possibly interactive, for UITabBarController, but under no circumstances are you able to obtain a transition coordinator from any of the child view controllers undergoing the transition; I regard this as a serious bug.

So, since you can't even get a transition coordinator in a situation where you are allowed to write a custom transition animation for a *built-in* parent view controller, obviously the chances of your getting one in a situation where you're trying to do your *own* parent view controller are zero.

Comment: So what are my options? Write my own? Abuse a hidden UINavigationController child view controller to get a transition coordinator?

Comment: You have not given anywhere near enough information in your question to reveal what you are doing or exactly what your goal is, let alone for me to be able to propose options. I have tried to answer the only factual programming issue I could find in your question. You are making up your own architecture so the architecture you make up is up to you.